# fitsSystemWindows effects on softkeyboard

Tags: android, android-xml, navigation-drawer

I have the following xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    **android:fitsSystemWindows="true"**
    >
```

my app has no actionbar or navigation bar.  Do i really need this attribute ? I am concerned what will be the affects when user tries a softkeyboard

Comment: Yes, otherwise the view will assume the status bar is still present or similar errors. see the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows

Comment: The docs are very confusing.  ok so im doing the right thing then? you can post an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, otherwise the view will assume the status bar is still present or similar errors. see the docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:fitsSystemWindows

Hope this helps. Whenever you're removing app/status bars from view then add that line to ensure that the view expands accordingly. Otherwise you'll get some weird UI errors. It only needs to be declared in the parent layout attribute of the XML view file as well, not the children (i..e buttons etc).